# Issue with reference ID SQL/ C#

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio

I have a front-end application which talks to a SQL server where it pulls information from a table and it is meant to find this information via the ID automatically assigned per row.

Below is the code I am currently using:

```
String ID = Request.Query["ID"];

try
{
    String connectionString = "Data Source=SQLTableDataSource;Integrated Security=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;";
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        //String sql = "SELECT TOP (1000) [ID]\r\n      ,[tNumber]\r\n      ,[tStatus]\r\n      ,[tApplication]\r\n      ,ISNULL([tType],'') [tType]\r\n      ,[tDateLogged]\r\n      ,[tDateUpdated]\r\n      ,[tDateClosed]\r\n      ,[tDateLastChecked]\r\n      ,[tUserLogged]\r\n      ,ISNULL ([tCurrentlyWith], '') [tCurrentlyWith]\r\n      ,[tLoggedOrAdHocTTL]\r\n  FROM [JB_DB].[dbo].[Tble_COF_IT_UK_Tickets] WHERE ID=@ID;";
        //String sql = "SELECT * FROM Tble_COF_IT_UK_Tickets WHERE ID=@ID;";
        String sql = "SELECT TOP (1000) [ID],[tNumber],[tStatus], [tApplication], [tType], [tDateLogged], ISNULL ([tDateUpdated], ' ') [tDateUpdated], ISNULL ([tDateClosed],' ') [tDateClosed], [tDateLastChecked], [tUserLogged], [tCurrentlyWith], [tLoggedOrAdHocTTL] FROM [JB_DB].[dbo].[Tble_COF_IT_UK_Tickets] WHERE ID=@ID;";
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID);
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    ticketInfo.ID = "" + reader.GetInt32(0);
                    ticketInfo.tNumber = reader.GetString(1);
                    ticketInfo.tStatus = reader.GetString(2);
                    ticketInfo.tApplication = reader.GetString(3);
                    ticketInfo.tType = reader.GetString(4);
                    ticketInfo.tDateLogged = reader.GetString(5);
                    ticketInfo.tDateUpdated = reader.GetString(6);
                    ticketInfo.tDateClosed = reader.GetString(7);
                    ticketInfo.tDateLastChecked = reader.GetString(8);
                    ticketInfo.tUserLogged = reader.GetString(9);
                    ticketInfo.tCurrentlyWith = reader.GetString(10);
                    ticketInfo.tLoggedOrAdHocTTL = reader.GetString(11);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

catch (Exception ex)
{
    errorMessage = ex.Message;
}
```

However, when I run the application and I get onto the ticket edit page, i receive the below error message:

`The parameterized query '(@ID nvarchar(4000))SELECT TOP (1000) [ID],[tNumber],[tStatus], ' expects the parameter '@ID', which was not supplied.`

I have tried to edit where the @ID is stated and changed the capitalisation of the ID as well but the same error occurs.

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Update. I have changed the code slightly and now receive a new error message:

'The variable name '@tDateUpdated' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure. Must declare the scalar variable "@tNumnber".'

Below is the code for the OnPost method:

```
public void OnPost()
{
    ticketInfo.ID = Request.Form["ID"];
    ticketInfo.tNumber = Request.Form["tNumber"];
    ticketInfo.tStatus = Request.Form["tStatus"];
    ticketInfo.tApplication = Request.Form["tApplication"];
    ticketInfo.tType = Request.Form["tType"];
    ticketInfo.tDateLogged = Request.Form["tDateLogged"];
    ticketInfo.tDateUpdated = Request.Form["tDateUpdated"];
    ticketInfo.tDateClosed = Request.Form["tDateClosed"];
    ticketInfo.tDateUpdated = Request.Form["tDateUpdated"];
    ticketInfo.tCurrentlyWith = Request.Form["tCurrentlyWith"];
    ticketInfo.tLoggedOrAdHocTTL = Request.Form["tLoggedOrAdHocTTL"];

    try
    {

        String connectionString = "Data Source=UK-TF-MUK-SQL01\\DEV;Initial Catalog=JB_DB;Integrated Security=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;";
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            String Sql = "UPDATE Tble_COF_IT_UK_Tickets " +
                "SET tNumber=@tNumnber, tStatus=@tStatus, tApplication=@tApplication, tType=@tType, tDateLogged=@tDateLogged, tDateUpdated=@tDateUpdated, tDateClosed=@tDateClosed, tDateLastUpdated=@tDateLastUpdated, tCurrentlyWith=@tCurrentlyWith, tLoggedOrAdHocTTL=@tLoggedOrAdHocTTL " +
                "WHERE ID=@ID;";

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(Sql, connection))
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tNumbar", ticketInfo.tNumber);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tStatus", ticketInfo.tStatus);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tApplication", ticketInfo.tApplication);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tType", ticketInfo.tType);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tDateLogged", ticketInfo.tDateLogged);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tDateUpdated", ticketInfo.tDateUpdated);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tDateClosed", ticketInfo.tDateClosed);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tDateUpdated", ticketInfo.tDateUpdated);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tCurrentlyWith", ticketInfo.tCurrentlyWith);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tLoggedOrAdHocTTL", ticketInfo.tLoggedOrAdHocTTL);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ticketInfo.ID);

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        errorMessage = ex.Message;
        return;
    }
```

Comment: You're trying to add the parameter `@ID`, but it seems that the SQL query itself doesn't have a placeholder for `@ID`. The SQL query string is fixed and doesn't include a` WHERE` clause to filter results based on the ID parameter.

Comment: You should modify your SQL query to include a `WHERE` clause that filters results by the ID column.

Comment: I have added the where clause to the string sql but, the same error message comes up.
Updated String sql = "SELECT TOP (1000) [ID],[tNumber],[tStatus], [tApplication], [tType], [tDateLogged], ISNULL ([tDateUpdated], ' ') [tDateUpdated], ISNULL ([tDateClosed],' ') [tDateClosed], [tDateLastChecked], [tUserLogged], [tCurrentlyWith], [tLoggedOrAdHocTTL] FROM [JB_DB].[dbo].[Tble_COF_IT_UK_Tickets] WHERE ID=@ID;";

Comment: Try to define the parameter explicitly: `command.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(ID);`

Comment: I've added the above code but now receive the error message:
The variable name '@tDateUpdated' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure. Must declare the scalar variable "@tNumnber".

Comment: @IT_Programmer, there is no "@tDateUpdated" in the code you posted so we cannot suggest where to fix your code.

Comment: @IT_Programmer, in the updated code, you are adding the "@tDateUpdated" twice.

Comment: I have removed the extra tDateUpdated but now the code will not pull through the information on the edit page nor will it update the table with the newest information I have inputted

Comment: I have resolved the last part of the issue by adjusting the string sql. It will now pull through all of the information except the dates

Answer (score 0):

Assuming one of the commented-out SQL statements with the `@ID` parameter name causes the error, make sure `Request.Query["ID"]` is not `NULL`.

Also, avoid [AddWithValue](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/).

Comment: The ID is set to automatically have an int applied to it in the SQL table each time there is a new row added to the table. The commented code has no impact on the rest of the code

Comment: @IT_Programmer, what is the actual value of `Request.Query["ID"]` at run time? The symptons suggest it is `null`.

Comment: Request.Query["ID"] points to the cshtml where it has:

<input type="hidden" name="ID" value="@Model.ticketInfo.ID" />

Ideally this code will look to get the ID of the row I want to edit and display all information in the row in the sql table to that id.

Comment: I have also added a paragraph which should display the ID number for the ticket which is being edited but this is not being pulled through. It looks like it is unable to pull the ID from the SQL table. However, when I run a query on the table, I can pull the ID column

Comment: @IT_Programmer, SO is a Q&A forum for specific targeted questions and does not work well for iterative debugging of different issues. Step through the code to capture the actual parameter values and if you get stuck, ask a new question for the specific problem. A SQL trace of the actual queries received by SQL Server may help troubleshoot.